# Qt color picking dialog , like gcolor2

Tags: qt, colors

Is there any way to let user pick color from screen ? Like the one in GIMP or gcolor2 , you click on anywhere on the screen , and it will tell you the color under mouse.

P.S: QColorDialog doesn't have the "pick" function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab a one-pixel portion of the entire screen and convert it into a [QPixmap](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html):

```
// crop screen in a pixmap containing only one pixel
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::grabWindow(QApplication::desktop()->winId(), mouse_pos_x, mouse_pos_y, 1, 1);
// convert pixmap to QImage so we can access pixel data crossplatform
QImage img = pixmap.toImage(); 
// image has only one pixel at coords (0,0), get its color
QColor col = QColor(img.pixel(0,0));
```

Then it's easy to extract the color. See function documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#grabWindow).

Comment: Can you be more specific please ? I just don't know how to retrieve the color.